# ref vs shallowRef for simple variables like string or number

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I know that `shallowRef` is lighter for resources because it watches only for changes in array keys or direct value changes. It does not watch, for example, deep inside object fields. Cool.

But what about strings or numbers. Does it make any sense to use `shallowRef` instead `ref` for those? Does it have any impact?

Or maybe ref for strings is by default shallow?

My thinking is - maybe it's better to ALWAYS use `shallowRef` for all data, and change it to normal `ref` ONLY when it's really needed (for ex. array with objects). This way, I will never use more resource consuming `ref` by mistake when it's not really needed.

Comment: refs of primitives can't be anything but shallow because primitives are not objects. Even if shallowRef is more efficient in vivo (this can be benchmarked), there are no indications that it's necessary for this

Comment: For primitives `shallowRef` calls `ref`. So, at least in theory, less code is executed if you use `ref` directly than using `shallowRef`, which evaluates a condition, then calls `ref` for you. But the performance loss is insignificant, so you might as well use `shallowRef` everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

### TLDR:

For [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive?retiredLocale=de) (string, number etc.) it does not make a difference, it's the same (with a very small `ref()` overhead)

[The docs state;](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#shallowref)

> `shallowRef()` is typically used for performance optimizations of large data structures, or integration with external state management systems.

Unlike `ref()`, the inner value of a shallow ref is stored and exposed as-is, and will not be made deeply reactive. Only the .value access is reactive.

### Use

`ref()` when..

- it's a primitive (for example 'string', true, 23, etc)
- it's an object you need to later reassign (like an array - more info here)

`shallowRef()` when..

- To avoid the deep conversion
- For big data structure where no deep reactivity is needed

`reactive()` when..

- it's an object you don't need to reassign, and you want to avoid the overhead of `ref()` (no .value access, see below)

### reactivity fun facts

- `reactive()` only takes objects, NOT JS primitives (String, Boolean, Number, BigInt, Symbol, null, undefined)
- `ref()` is calling `reactive()` behind the scenes

Since `reactive()` works for objects and `ref()` calls `reactive()`, objects work for both
**BUT, `ref()` has a `.value` property for reassigning, `reactive()` does not have this and therefore CANNOT be reassigned**